# Conveying the meaning of "Last nail in the coffin" with "(le) dernier clou dans le cercueil"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

The other day, I was trying to convey the meaning of the

> Last nail in the coffin.

The literal translation

> Dernier clou dans le cercueil.

seems to be unknown to natifs. (Some students didn't remember/know the word cercueil but that's another story:-)!).

Trying to find other possible translations we encounter "coup fatal" et "sonner le glas". The former was understood, the latter considered a bit archaic.

What are some common colloquial ways to express the meaning of the original English sentence?

As an example of usage:

> An employee keeps arriving late for work. His boss gives him a first
>   warning. The employee is late again. His boss gives him a second
>   warning. The employee is late again. His boss gives him a third
>   warning, and says, “If you’re late again, you’re fired.” The employee
>   shows up the next day 2 hours late. The boss says, “Your late arrival
>   today is the final nail in the coffin. You’re fired.

Comment: I am surprised your native interlocutors did not understand, or at least make a link with another phrase: the idiom "le clou de mon/ton/son cercueil" exists in French, albeit with a somewhat different use and meaning. It means "to be something painful that will torment presumably until the death of the person (or ending of something)". Ex: "mon fils est un bon-à-rien, il est le clou  de mon cercueil".

Comment: The translation would be different depending on the case, but on some of them you could use "*ça a fini de l'achever*", "*ça a fini de l'enterrer*", something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En français cela se traduit très bien par la phrase idiomatique « *la goutte qui fait déborder le vase* ». Le cas d'usage trouvé [ici](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-expression-the-final-nail-in-the-coffin-mean) rend cela certain.

*Exemple*

For example: An employee keeps arriving late for work. His boss gives him a first warning. The employee is late again. His boss gives him a second warning. The employee is late again. His boss gives him a third warning, and says, “If you’re late again, you’re fired.” The employee shows up the next day 2 hours late. The boss says, “Your late arrival today is the final nail in the coffin. You’re fired.”

*Traduction des deux dernières phrases*
[…] Le patron dit « Votre retard encore aujourd'hui est la goutte qui fait déborder le vase. Je vous mets à la porte.».

L'idiome qui est discuté dans cette question ne doit pas être confondu avec "nail in the coffin of (something)" or equivalently "nail in (sb's/sth's) coffin". La partie déterminante de « nail » est libre : "the last nail », « a nail », « a few nails », « the final nail », etc.

Dans ce cas la traduction ne sera pas unique car il y en  aura au moins une pour chaque partie déterminante.

- the last/final nail in the coffin of the very poor
  *ce qui a rendu intolérable la situation déjà précaire des très pauvres*
- a decisive nail in the coffin of the company
  *un coup important dans ce qui contribue à la destruction de la firme*
- a nail in the coffin of his project to build a house
  *une étape dans ce qui a amené la fin de son projet de construire une maison*

Comment: Merci ! Sonner le glas est désuet ?

Comment: @Dimitris « Sonner le glas » ne correspond pas bien ; c'est une expression qui veut dire que la fin se fait sentir, qu'elle est proche, mais pas que c'est la fin.  Loc. Sonner le glas de qqc. Annoncer sa **fin imminente**. Sonner le glas d'une espérance, d'une défaite, d'un régime politique, d'une institution. — imminent : qui menace, qui est sur le point de se produire.

Comment: Doesn't "last nail in the coffin" convey the idea that someone is doing something against someone else? Like saying "you are putting the last nail in my coffin"? If so you can't say that with "la goutte d'eau".

Comment: And "last nail in the coffin", to me at least, conveys the idea that it ends something, like `this political decision was the last nail in the coffin of the very poor`, where `cette décision politique était la goutte d'eau qui fait déborder le vase pour les plus pauvres` means that now they are very angry. If you say `Cette fois, c'est la goutte d'eau qui fait déborder le vase !`, that means it is war, but with the coffin expression, I understand the opposite, they are now unable to fight back.

Comment: @Destal The expression discussed here is " …in **the** coffin"  and it is an idiom;  you wouldn't distort it and say "You are putting the last last nail in my coffin" I think unless to make a pun and personally I see no way to do that cleanly  (better be careful with such manipulations). No, it does not mean necessarily to do Something against  somebody; it means to do something too many times, one time too many precisely, and that is the cause for a drastic happening.

Comment: @LPH but even without changing the idiom, when I hear `this political decision is the last nail in the coffin of the poor` it sounds to me like they are *dead and burried* and can't fight back. Where `cette décision politique est la goutte d'eau qui fait déborder le vase pour les pauvres` sounds like they've had enough and are going to *flood the streets with their rage*.

Comment: @Destal In your case that's right, but this is so  because you use a variant : "the last nail in the coffin **of something**"; you have to make that something precise.

Comment: @LPH I agree with Destal, "*La goutte d'eau*" is analog to "*The last straw on the camel's back*", NOT the last nail in the coffin.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat The correct expression is only "the straw that breaks the camel's back". What else than the "last drop" is the last nail, that nail that brings about the dreaded event, the catastrophe, the spill of water ?

Comment: @LPH L'idée n'est pas du tout la même. Pour le *last nail*, le sujet a subi des coups, des échecs, il était **déjà mal en point** et un dernier a fini par avoir raison de lui. Si c'est une personne elle abandonne, si c'est un projet, une théorie, elle est abandonnée, si c'est une entreprise, elle fait faillite. Pour *the straw*, le sujet supporte, supporte, et fini par craquer. C'est très rare que ce ne soit pas utilisé pour une personne ou un groupe de personnes.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Dans l'exemple qui parait dans mas question il n'y a pas de personne qui soit dans un « cercueil » ; on demande seulement à cette personne d'être à l'heure, il n'y a ni coups contre elle ni échecs de sa part. Je doute beaucoup qu'il y ait la grande différence que vous percevez. Néanmoins, restons en à cette conclusion de désaccord.